# how i can access the internal android device information ?

Tags: android

I have to send this jasonObject to get the response

["device_id" : "****", 
        "device_locale" : "ar",
        "os" : "android" ]

how i can access this information : device id  and the local language ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the Build object.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html

For instance,

Build.BOARD

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below util class to get the device ID and the Locale.

```
public class DeviceInfoUtil {

    public static String getDeviceId(Context context){
        return Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
    }
    public static String getDeviceLocale(){
        return Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();
    }

 }
```